# Ordered Asynchronous AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script that performs several functions and I want to update the user as the functions are completed.  I have nested `$.ajax()` calls with each subsequent call in the previous call's `success` block.

There are a total of 4 calls made for each loop.  Let's call them `scan_1` through `scan_4`.  The `success` block of `scan_1` calls `scan_2` and so on down the chain.

For example, let's say I'm looping over 3 objects.  I want the process to go like this:

Loop 1

- scan_1
- scan_2
- scan_3
- scan_4

Loop 2

- scan_1
- scan_2
- scan_3
- scan_4

Loop 3

- scan_1
- scan_2
- scan_3
- scan_4

The problem is that it's running through all the `scan_1` calls first.  I must be missing something, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

For reference, here is a snippet of `scan_1` (irrelevant stuff snipped):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:       'GET',
        url:        url,
        data:       'do=scan&step=1&' + string,
        dataType:   'json',
        success:    function (result)
        {
            if(result.proceed == 'true')
            {
                $('#scan_progress').append(result.message);
                scan_2();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#scan_progress').append(result.message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need [to use jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). It basically allows you to chain multiple event handlers to the jQuery Ajax object and gives you finer control over when the callbacks are invoked.

Further reading:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg723713
- http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Comment: I think this is my answer.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @SenorAmor What did you end-up using? I ask just because my answer shows an example of how to use deferred objects with your code.

Comment: @SenorAmor Would also be good for the community if you were to post what you ended up using so that anyone else who comes here with the same question you had will see what you ended up using.

Comment: Hi guys.  Sorry, I've been busy with other projects and haven't been able to fully finish this one so I don't have an exact answer, but jQuery's deferred has suited me well so far.  Hope this helps some!

Answer (score 1):

It's asynchronous - the "success" fires sometime in the future. The script does not wait for it to respond. Since you're firing off three requests in your loop, they will all be "scan1".

"scan_2" will be called as each request completes.

Change the request to synchronous if you want to control the order of events.

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that synchronous calls locks up the browser (save for Firefox), and doesn't output any information until the entire loop has completed.  This is basically a text-based loading bar, and I know there are similar scripts that perform what I want to do without causing the browser to freeze.  I just don't know how.

Comment: Then you need to create an "event queue" - issue one request at a time, then grab the next event in the queue and fire it off.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting by sending off three ajax calls at once.

Scan1 (loop 1)
Scan1 (loop 2)
Scan1 (loop 3)

When each Scan 1 completes, it's subsequent Scan 2, and then Scan 3 are called.

What did you actually want to happen? Scan 1 2 and 3 of loop 1, then 1 2 and 3 of loop 2, and then 1 2 and 3 of loop 3? That would require more nesting, or possibly deferred objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `success` callback for each `$.ajax()` call, you can store each set of AJAX requests (their jqXHR objects) in an array and wait for all of them to resolve:

```
function scan_1 () {

    //setup array to store jqXHR objects (deferred objects)
    var jqXHRs = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {

        //push a new index onto the array, `$.ajax()` returns an object that will resolve when the response is returned
        jqXHRs[jqXHRs.length] = $.ajax({
            type:       'GET',
            url:        url,
            data:       'do=scan&step=1&' + string,
            dataType:   'json'
        });
    }

    //wait for all four of the AJAX requests to resolve before running `scan_2()`
    $.when(jqXHRs).then(function () {
        if(result.proceed == 'true') {
            scan_2();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems working heavily with SharePoint web services - you often need to pull data from multiple sources to generate input for a single process.

To solve it I embedded this kind of functionality into my AJAX abstraction library. You can easily define a request which will trigger a set of handlers when complete. However each request can be defined with multiple http calls. Here's the component (and detailed documentation):

[DPAJAX at DepressedPress.com](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_ajax/)

This simple example creates one request with three calls and then passes that information, in the call order, to a single handler:

```
    // The handler function 
function AddUp(Nums) { alert(Nums[1] + Nums[2] + Nums[3]) }; 

    // Create the pool 
myPool = DP_AJAX.createPool(); 

    // Create the request 
myRequest = DP_AJAX.createRequest(AddUp); 

    // Add the calls to the request 
myRequest.addCall("GET", "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm", [5,10]); 
myRequest.addCall("GET", "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm", [4,6]); 
myRequest.addCall("GET", "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm", [7,13]); 

    // Add the request to the pool 
myPool.addRequest(myRequest);
```

Note that unlike many of the other solutions provided this method does not force single threading of the calls being made - each will still run as quickly (or as slowly) as the environment allows but the single handler will only be called when all are complete. It also supports the setting of timeout values and retry attempts if your service is a little flakey.

I've found it insanely useful (and incredibly simple to understand from a code perspective).  No more chaining, no more counting calls and saving output.  Just "set it and forget it".